# How to get the users with the sort by birth-date by month?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have to sort the data by birth-date of the user. But it can be sort by the month not by the year or date. I need data of user as well.

I haven't idea how can I do that with the get all field of user like first_name, last_name etc.

I have try this query:

```
 $employees = User::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%M %Y') as months"),)
       ->groupBy('months')
       ->get();
```

Comment: Well I don't have any clue either before I see anything you have tried to accomplish you're idea-ness-less ..

Comment: Just edit the question if you would like to supply additional info.

Comment: @dbf I have update you can check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to sort your users by month of the birthdate and then get the users:

```
User::select(
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%m') as month"), 'first_name', 'last_name',
    )->orderByDesc('month')->get();
```

Note that you can also use orderByAcs to order the users ascending

Comment: but how can I get the users first_name, last_name because it return only "month" in attribute array.

Comment: @Kishan `User::select(['first_name', 'last_name', DB::raw(...)]) ...`; it only returned `month`, since that's the only column you selected.

Comment: @Kishan I have updated my answer so that you can also get the first_name and last_name

Comment: @Kishan be friends first with Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent) dealing ORM.

Comment: @TimLewis I have try  this query:
`

 $employees = User::select(['first_name','last_name'],
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%m') as month"),
        )->orderByDesc('birth_date')->get();

`
But I get only first_name and last_name!

Comment: Because you put `DB::raw()` outside of the array... Also, you did `orderByDesc('birth_date')`... Look at my example vs yours, and the answer, and use the correct syntax. `User::select(['first_name', 'last_name', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(birth_date,'%m') as month")])->orderBy('month', 'DESC')->get();`.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for your support can you tell me how select your answer as answer?

Comment: I didn't post an answer, I've been posting comments that supports this answer (it was _almost_ correct). Please considering selecting this answer (with the ✅ next to it) to properly close this questions. Thanks!